# Movie where teens escape the cops to an underground tunnel filled with monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This movie looks like it was from 2013-15. The first scene starts with a party. The cops show up where a gang of some boys and girls escape them and they end up underground.

Under the ground there are some monsters that are kept in water for preservation... some die and then the protagonists survive as always, after killing the doctor who made those.

One remarkable scene is that a police woman comes out of the underground looking very weak... but then when she comes up only half of her body is left after the monsters had eaten the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Underground* (2011).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1811371):

> A group of friends fight for their lives against the lethal and ravenous creatures lurking beneath the Earth's surface. The group finds themselves at the mercy of creatures genetically engineered by the military to be expendable in battle. Though they fought countless battles in Iraq, these friends never knew real fear until they went underground.

The details match:

- it starts with an illegal rave party;
- the group goes underground;
- clichéd horror movie stuff happens, and at least one guy is dragged by the creatures in a pond; *(I'd take a screenshot, but it's really to blurry to be an identifier)*
- Doctor describes his creations with a passionate look ([this guy's face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqgKD.png) rings a bell?);
- and when a policewoman comes to see what's going on, well... Only the upper half of her body comes out ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqFiG.jpg), **warning NSFW gory**).

---

Found with the Google query `Movie teens escape cops underground tunnel monsters` (hat tip to [TLC](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) for the better title!), which returned [this list of underground horror movies](https://www.gamesradar.com/20-underground-horror-movies/2/), the description for *Underground* seemed "promising":

> During an illegal rave, a group of partygoers take a wrong turn and find themselves trapped in a military bunker.